# Why is SO slow when accessing my review history?

Tags: support, bug

Loading the [first](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/history?page=1) page of my review history works fine, but going to the 5000th page takes 20 seconds and accessing the last page (page 7341) takes about 30 seconds after which I'm taken to a [page](https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/review/reopen/history) that says "Oops, something went bad" with a picture of a guy that looks like me.

Why is it so slow and is there a way around this? I really want to see my review history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the *entire system* that has 7341 pages of reopen review history. You personally only have 100 pages - and the [last page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/701092/0x499602d2?tab=activity&sort=reviews&page=100) loads pretty much instantly for me.

As for why accessing that last page is slow, possibly either the data is so cold (there appear to be on the order of 10 million review records) that the attempt to retrieve it is exceeding some timeout, or possibly there's some bad data back there that's breaking something.